# Pivot like number manipulation in R

Tags: r

I am trying to nest two subset data inside aggregate. but it returns different length of data and hence unable to compute.
What options do i have?

```
newfile<- aggregate(cbind(subset(IVA,IVA$IVR.Agent =="Agent"),subset(IVA,IVA$IVR.Agent=="IVR")) ~ IVA$OrderNo, FUN = length, rm.action = TRUE)
```

Below is the error that I got

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 25039, 4585
```

I am trying to make a **pivot table** that will show Agent count and IVR count in separate columns just like in excel, if for a specific order there is no IVR it shows null otherwise its count.

DataSet looks like this

```
OrderNo IVR/Agent
    A1  IVR
    B1  Agent
    A2  Agent
    B2  IVR
    A3  Agent
    B3  Agent
    A4  Agent
    B4  Agent
    A5  IVR
    B5  Agent
```

[image: Pivot]

Comment: It's really difficult (actually impossible) to give you any answer without displaying how your data is structured.  However, my preferred method for pivot tables is `ddply` in the `plyr` package or if you're familiar with `dplyr` try `group_by`

Comment: Please review the [guidelines for posting a minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have just added the structure of dataset above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you wanna check out the `reshape2` package and the `cast` function.  Check out the code below:

```
# install.packages('reshape2') # only run if you haven't downloaded before
library(reshape2)

datCast <- dcast(dat, OrderNo ~ IVR.Agent, fun.aggregate = length, margins = T)

datCast
   OrderNo Agent IVR (all)
1       A1     0   1     1
2       A2     1   0     1
3       A3     1   0     1
4       A4     1   0     1
5       A5     0   1     1
6       B1     1   0     1
7       B2     0   1     1
8       B3     1   0     1
9       B4     1   0     1
10      B5     1   0     1
11   (all)     7   3    10
```

Comment: I got the below error after i ran the code.                       datCast <- dcast(newdata, OrderNo ~ IVR.Agent,fun.aggregate=length,margins=T)
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, vars) : undefined columns selected

Comment: Do you have `reshape2` loaded? R's also case sensitive.  Can you confirm the capitalized letters?

Comment: Yes reshape is loaded,

Comment: library(reshape2)
newdata <- data.frame(IVA$OrderNo, IVA$IVR.Agent )
datCast <- dcast(newdata, OrderNo ~ IVR.Agent,fun.aggregate=length,margins=T)

Comment: @Shoaibkhanz, reshape != reshape2.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you did. Try: newdata <- data.frame(OrderNo = IVA$OrderNo, IVR.Agent = IVA$IVR.Agent).  With not defining the names of the columns, it defaults to to include everything.

Comment: > newdata <- data.frame(OrderNo= IVA$OrderNo, IVR.Agent= IVA$IVR.Agent )
> datCast <- dcast(newdata, OrderNo ~ IVR.Agent,fun.aggregate=length,margins=T)
Using IVR.Agent as value column: use value.var to override.

Comment: I got this error;Using IVR.Agent as value column: use value.var to override.

Comment: @AnandaMahto that was a typo, I am indeed using reshape2

Comment: I don't think that's an error, but a message.  It's defaulting to IVR.Agent

Answer (score 2):

If your data is called `myData` the following seems to be what you need.

```
table(myData)

# which yields

       IVR.Agent
OrderNo Agent IVR
     A1     0   1
     A2     1   0
     A3     1   0
     A4     1   0
     A5     0   1
     B1     1   0
     B2     0   1
     B3     1   0
     B4     1   0
     B5     1   0
```

Just add up the columns for a grand total if you want one.

```
gt <- rowSums( table(s) )
```

or

```
tab <- table(s)
gt <- tab[,1] + tab[,2]
```